# Convert JSON file to CSV using powershell in SSIS

Tags: json, powershell, ssis

We have a Web Service which is in JSON format(script) that needs to be converted to csv files and dropped to a fileshare location using powershell.
All this needs to be captured on running a SSIS package.
How can this be achieved?

```
# Set the filename to have the date suffix.
$fileName = "2758_RS-DM_AIRData" + (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd_hh) + ".csv"
$location = "C:\ExtractFilePowerShellWebService\Data"
New-Item -ItemType file -Name $fileName -Path $location 

# delete if file exist
$FileName2 = (Join-Path $location $fileName)
if (Test-Path $FileName2) {
  Remove-Item $FileName2

}

# Capture data from AIR Web Service

$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("A", "B", "C")
$Json = $WebClient.Downloadstring("https://air.ciostage.accenture.com/ExternalServices/Application-service/Application(2758)")     
$jsonserial= New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer 
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength = [int]::MaxValue
$appCollection = @()
$appObj = $jsonserial.DeserializeObject($Json)
foreach($app in $appObj.value){

        $appObject = New-Object System.Object 
        $appObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ApplicationId" -Value $app.ApplicationId 
        $appObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ApplicationNm" -Value $app.ApplicationNm
        $appObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Application Tier" -Value $app.ServiceLevelOfferingNm
        $appObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Application Status" -Value $app.AppStatusNm
        #$appObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Description" -Value $app.Description
        #$appObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Acronym" -Value $app.Acronym
        #$appObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Url" -Value $app.Url
        $appCollection += $appObject
}

#$appCollection | Export-Csv -Path "C:\ExtractFilePowerShellWebService\Data\2758_RS-DM_AIRData.csv" -notypeinformation

#extract data into CSV file.
$appCollection | Export-Csv  -Path (Join-Path $location $fileName) -notypeinformation
```

When I run the script, csv file is created in the location mentioned but it is empty

Comment: Why does it need to be in a SSIS package? Just call the powershell script directly

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid because an SSIS package does a lot more than just convert one format to another. It will load, transform, lookup, combine and bulk load data from a LOT of different sources and send it to a LOT of different targets. AND validate fields, sizes etc to ensure you won't truncate data by accident, or try to pass fewer columns than those expected, or send a number to a string field. Trying to do the same with a Powershell script can be .... fun

Comment: @Aiswarya what does the JSON file look like? Converting/loading flat objects should be easy. Converting nested objects would require transformations eg with `Select` to flatten them or extract only the necessary fields

Comment: @Aiswarya furthermore, SQL Server 2016 introduced JSON support and querying. *Maybe* you could load individual Json rows into a table, then query them

Comment: Just establishing whether SSIS is required or not. If all they are doing is converting JSON to CSV then it's probably overkill.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid there is no need, since this is a Powershell question. As ConnorLSW answered, Powershell already supports *some* level of JSON manipulation.

Comment: So now you are agreeing that SSIS is overkill?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid on the contrary. How are you going to import and transform that CSV? I'm saying that asking about SSIS is not relevant

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding each other.

Comment: I think we agree that a question that contains JSON, CSV, Powershell and SSIS is clearly overcomplicating things!

Comment: I have attached the code. Its very confusing for me, can you provide a step by step explanation. I need to get the column data from this file to the csv file and drop to a location in the Share file

Comment: Also to note: I have no idea of Powershell! Iam developing a SSIS package, where this is one of the requirement

Comment: When you run the script do you get an error? What happens? I suggest you first debug the script in a powershell console (I use Windows Powershell ISE). Please don't say 'nothing happens' or 'it doesn't work'. Please read this guide on debugging powershell scripts. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise

Comment: And as also mentioned there many other (probably simpler) ways to solve a 'convert json to scv' problem but we don't have any background and you say you must use SSIS so unless you can clarify, we will pursue that solution

Comment: When I run the script, csv file is created in the location mentioned. It is empty though.

Comment: OK so next step is follow the guide I linked to and step through the script and find out what's going on. I will add your info to the question

Comment: Also please note I have edited your code and **REMOVED THE CREDENTIALS** in it. You shouldn't post credentials in a public place

Comment: It _could_ be this line: `$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength = [int]::MaxValue` - you haven't defined `MaxValue` anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your data is already in a format that will suit being in a csv, as Json has a lot of elements which csv cannot display, i'm using [ConvertTo-Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) in this example to generate a Json file :

```
Get-Process | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1 | Out-File .\file.json
```

note the `-Depth 1` which means no nested arrays etc. will be carried over.

Then I can convert that to to a csv using [ConvertFrom-Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) and the following:

```
(Get-Content .\file.json | ConvertFrom-Json) | Select Name,Handles,VM,PM | Export-Csv .\file.csv
```

Comment: In other words, the OP should use [Convert-From](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i don't think `gc .. | convertfrom-json | export-csv` works though, covnertfrom-json is weird when piped directly.

Comment: The answer will be a lot more useful if you explain that you *can* convert to/from Json already, which functions to use and add links to them.